# The message port closed before a response was received

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to communicate my contentScript.js and backgroundscript.js using chrome messaging api. First when I tried to send one message from contentScript.js it worked fine and now I need to send two messages but  it throws  "The message port closed before a response was received".

this is contentScipt.js

```
var scrapeButton = document.getElementById('clickToScrape'); 
scrapeButton.addEventListener("click", function(){
spin.style.display = "block";
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(JSON.stringify({"type": "newScraping", 
"url": input.value, "cookie": cookieSession}),function(response){
  if (response){spin.style.display = "none"};

});
}
  )

var updateButton = document.getElementById("clickToUpdate");
updateButton.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
spin.style.display = "block";
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(JSON.stringify({"type": "update",
"url": input.value, "cookie": cookieSession}),function(response){
 if (response){spin.style.display = "none"};

});
}
)
```

and this is the background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (response, sender, sendResponse) {

console.log(response)
const body = response;
if(response.type == "newScraping"){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/scrape_company", // URL de l'API
    data: body,
    contentType : "application/json",
    dataType: 'json',  
    
    success: function (result) {
        sendResponse(result);
        alert(result);
    },
    error: function () {
        sendResponse("Veuillez patienter jusqu'à ce que le scraping soit terminé");
        alert("Veuillez patienter jusqu'à ce que le scraping soit terminé");   
    }

})}
else if (response.type == "update"){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/update_company", // URL de l'API
        data: body,
        contentType : "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',  
        
        success: function (result) {
            sendResponse(result);
            alert(result);
        },
        error: function () {
            sendResponse("Veuillez patienter jusqu'à ce que le scraping soit terminé");
            alert("Veuillez patienter jusqu'à ce que le scraping soit terminé");   
        }
    
    })

}; return true 

});
```

Nb: I'm using also chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener API that listens for a message coming from another script.js it works fine

Answer (score 1):

if anyone is facing that, the problem here is the type of the response received in background.js (which is string) the solution is simple just use :  `response_obj = JSON. parse(response)` to convert it to an object.